# How do I fix my paypal button 'total sum' in React?

Tags: reactjs, paypal

Ive got my Paypal buttons on on my cart page but my homebrew is coming up with an error message to do with my total sum inside my paypal code. Its advising me I need curly braces but when I put in the extra braces it still doesnt work. Can anyone advise on what to do? Thank in advance. Below is my cart page

```
import React, { useState }from 'react';
import productsData  from './data/products.json';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link, useParams } from "react- 
router-dom";
import { PayPalScriptProvider, PayPalButtons } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";



export default function Cart({ cart, setCart }) {


const [products, setProducts] = useState(productsData.productsData);


const getTotalSum = () => {
return cart.reduce(
  (sum, { cost, quantity }) => sum + cost * quantity,
  0
);
};

  const clearCart = () => {
  setCart([]);
  };

const setQuantity = (product, amount) => {
const newCart = [...cart];
newCart.find(
  (item) => item.name === product.name
).quantity = amount;
setCart(newCart);
};

const removeFromCart = (productToRemove) => {
setCart(
  cart.filter((product) => product !== productToRemove)
);
};

return (
<>
  <h1>Cart</h1>
    {cart.length > 0 && (
      <button onClick={clearCart}>Clear Cart</button>
    )}
    <div className="products">
      {cart.map((product, idx) => (
        <div className="product" key={idx}>
          <h3>{product.name}</h3>
          <h4> £ {product.cost}</h4>
          <input
            value={product.quantity}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setQuantity(
                product,
                parseInt(e.target.value)
              )
            }
          />
          <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
          <button onClick={() => removeFromCart(product)}>
            Remove
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>

    <div>Total Cost: £{getTotalSum()}</div>

 <PayPalScriptProvider options={{"client-id": import.meta.env.VITE_CLIENT_ID }}>
 <PayPalButtons  createOrder={(data, actions) => {
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [
            {
              amount: {
                value: {getTotalSum()},
              },
            },
          ],
        });
      }}

      onApprove={async (data, actions) => {
        const details = await actions.order.capture();
        const name = details.payer.name.given_name;
        alert("Transaction completed by " + name);
      }} />
   </PayPalScriptProvider>



</>
);
}
```

Comment: Your "homebrew"? What does this mean in this context? Where and what *exactly* is the error? Why is `getTotalSum()` in curly brackets inside the `createOrder` handler function?

Comment: Ive just deleted the curly braces around my get total sum and it seems to have worked. Thank you